# How to update a record using MVC3 WebApi and AngularJs . Getting this error : Non-static method requires a target.<

Tags: c#, angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am working on MVC 3 project and i just need to add a new feature and to do so i'm using angularjs and webApi. to achieve this i'm doing the following below:

so i have a service function in angular side of things like this:

```
 function Send(params) {
            var request = $http.post('/api/updatelostorder/update/', params);
            return request;
        }
```

Params  is an object like this

```
params = {QouteLineId: 1, LostReasonId: 5}
```

Server (C#) side of things:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
        [HttpPost]
        public  bool Update(QuotesTable model)
        {
            try
            {
                var t = db.QuoteLines.Single(x => x.QuoteLineID == model.QuoteLineID);
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    model.LostReasonId = model.LostReasonId;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return true;

        }
```

Now i'm not sure to what i'm doing wrong here but when i run my project and try to update a record i get the following error:

> Non-static method requires a target.<

Does anyone know what this means and also does anyone know a better way to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Where exactly in your C# are you getting the error?

Comment: it doesn't really say where exactly . i just getting when i hit via developer tools.

Comment: You can keep a debugger point in your code and try to find out where exactly are you getting the error. That would help in finding out what could be cause for it. Try adding if(db != null) before  var t = db.QuoteLines.Single(x => x.QuoteLineID == model.QuoteLineID);

Comment: where to get value the "db" variable? It may also be null?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is several wrong pieces in your code. I'll try to enumerate them, but I advise you to study a little more on how MVC and Entity Framework works in general:

1 - `[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]`

Is there a reason why you marked your POST method also accept a GET? This really doesn't make any sense. If it is a POST, then, only `[HttpPost]` should be used.

2 - `var t = db.QuoteLines ...`

You are querying the database (I'm assuming db here is a instance of your EF context class), storing the possible result into `t` but never actually use `t` to update its values.

3 - `if (ModelState.IsValid)`

What is the purpose of this if statement? `model.LostReasonId = model.LostReasonId;`

4 - `db.SaveChanges`

Since you already queried the database and stored the entity in the `t` variable, you don't need to attach anything in the context. All the updates should go to the `t` variable.

Also, you need to move this code inside the try/catch block and not outside, since this could also throw exceptions.

This is how it should look like after some refactoring:

```
[HttpPost]
public  bool Update(QuotesTable model)
{
    try
    {
        var t = db.QuoteLines.SingleOrDefault(x => x.QuoteLineID == model.QuoteLineID);     

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Throw some exception or any other validation logic
            //only if model is not valid.
        }

        if(t == null)
        {
            //Throw some exception or any other validation logic
            //only if the QuoteLine doesn't exist
        }       

        //I believe you meant something like this?
        t.LostReasonId = model.LostReasonId;

        //More updates here in t...

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Try this and see if the error still occurs. It should work now.